# Replace only if "." is the only value in a data frame column in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a data frame that I am working with where missing values are specified with a dot (".") and I'm trying to replace the missing data with "Not_Given". However, some other columns have "." within the string that is part of a longer string. I've set up a mini data frame to test the replace method below:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], "b": ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"], "c": ["a", "b", "c", ".", "a.b"]})
test_df
```

which prints out the following data frame:

[image]

I've written the following code to try to replace the single "." value (index 3 of column 3):

```
for col in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    test_df[col] = test_df[col].str.replace(".", "Not_Given")

test_df
```

This returns the output:

[image]

Obviously this is replacing every "." that it comes across in the data frame, so the values 1.0 get replaced with 1Not_Given0.

I have also tried the following code:

```
for col in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    test_df[col] = test_df[col].str.replace("\.{1,1}", "Not_Given")
```

which still has the same output as above.

Is there a way to only replace if there is only a "." value with no other characters?

Comment: Why not use `NaN` to indicate missing data? Can you share more of your program? There might be other design changes to make.

Comment: I did not generate the data set that I'm working with. They decided to specify missing data with "." and I'm just trying to work out the code on a simplified case.

Comment: That’s no issue, you can simply replace a period with `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Pandas [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function:

```
test_df.replace({'.': 'Not_Given'})
```

Result:

```
   a    b          c
0  1  1.0          a
1  2  2.0          b
2  3  3.0          c
3  4  4.0  Not_Given
4  5  5.0        a.b
```

Comment: The best answer. I don't see how regex is ever needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, maybe a simple expression such as,

```
^\s*\.\s*$
```

might work OK here.

We've also added `\s*` just in case, there might be spaces before or after the `.`.

#### Test

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], "b": [
                       "1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"], "c": ["a", "b", "c", ".", "a.b"]})


test_df['c'] = test_df['c'].str.replace(r'^\s*\.\s*$', 'Not_Given')
print(test_df)
```

#### Output

```
   a    b          c
0  1  1.0          a
1  2  2.0          b
2  3  3.0          c
3  4  4.0  Not_Given
4  5  5.0        a.b
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TdpPBS/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/TdpPBS/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Answer (score 1):

You could use `"^\.$"`

```
test_df[col].str.replace("^\.$", "Not_Given")
```

or simply

```
test_df[col][ test_df[col] == '.' ] = "Not_Given"
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], "b": ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"], "c": ["a", "b", "c", ".", "a.b"]})

for col in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    #test_df[col] = test_df[col].str.replace("^\.$", "Not_Given")
    test_df[col][ test_df[col] == '.' ] = "Not_Given"
print(test_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df['c'] == '.'] = 'Not_Given'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different **idiomatic** solutions:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df[df.eq('.')] = np.NaN

df = df.map({'.': np.NaN})

df = df.replace(to_replace='.', value=np.NaN)

df = df.replace({'.': np.NaN})
```